# has_ancestry and active model serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers, ancestry

I have a model `Category`

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attributes :id, :name, :order, :x, :y, :z
  has_ancestry
end
```

In my controller, I can use the following to get the whole tree as JSON

```
Category.first.subtree.arrange_serializable
```

But this returns all DB attributes such as `created_at` or `id`

I wanted to use the active model serializer to shape my output without losing the tree structure.

```
class CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  # Children is the subtree provided by ancestry
  attributes :name, :x, :children
end
```

Controller

```
class CategoryController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    category = Category.first
    render :json => category
  end
end
```

The code above will only show the first sub level, but not the children of the children.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To use arrangement, we need to pass an additional parameter to serializer, you can do it this way:

```
category.subtree.arrange_serializable do |parent, children|
  CategorySerializer.new(parent, scope: { children: children })
end
```

And here's how you can take that parameter in serializer:

```
class CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :order, :children

  def children
    scope.to_h[:children]
  end
end
```

You may also want to take a look at [this test](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/blob/2fa4381e0e21289d6800772d7f67d16efa65c4f8/test/concerns/arrangement_test.rb#L38-L58) to have a better understanding how `arrange_serializable` works.

Comment: This does not completely work. It serializes the root element and then merges all sublevel catagories in one list and renders them out without paying attention to the serializer

Comment: please, show how you use this code (at the controller, possibly).

Comment: Thanks, I also found this snippet in the docs. But how to use this serializer. I tried it and it would only apply it the first element, not the descending onces

Comment: Thanks a lot so far .. I tried this out but didn't get it to work for some reason. If I do `category = Category.first` and try to work on `category.arrange_serializable`, it throughs an exception (unknown method).. Only `category.subtree.arrange_serializable` works, but does not use the serializer at all (not even the first element)

Comment: What does my code return if you call it with `category.subtree.arrange_serializable`?

Answer (score 1):

In AMS 10.x (master branch) we can support external parameters in such way:

```
class CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :order, :children

  def children
    instance_options[:children]
    # or instance_options[:children]&.as_json
  end
end
```

Next you can simply pass children to the serializer:

```
category.subtree.arrange_serializable do |parent, children|
  CategorySerializer.new(parent, children: children)
end
```

or

```
category.subtree.arrange_serializable do |parent, children|
  ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource(parent, children: children)
end
```